# PrimeNG datatable: customize filter input

Tags: angular, primeng

I need to toggle visibility of filter inputs placed in table header.
I tried to do it this way:

```
<input type="text"
       class="ui-column-filter ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all"
       [value]="dt.filters[col.field] ? dt.filters[col.field].value : ''"             
       (keyup)="dt.onFilterKeyup($event.value,col.field,col.filterMatchMode)"
       *ngIf="filterIsShown"/>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/o2wLmXHMb1uI5EvBmucr?p=preview

But I have an error **`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filters' of undefined`**

So where I should get `dt.filters` object?

------UPDATED-------

Thanks PierreDuc for answer, but filter still doesn't work :(

I used all parameters accordingly to template I found here https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/datatable/datatable.ts

Here's updated plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/2MWxw0rfcLsDxmuIYRv9?p=preview

Comment: Not PrimeFaces related but PrimeNG...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add `#dt` as a variable to your `<p-dataTable>`. This creates a template variable linking to your `DataTable` instance:

[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/YYU0UbFpH6uSjc4QpbsC?p=preview)

```
<p-dataTable ... #dt>
```

And you have to change your `keyup` method to pass the right value:

```
(keyup)="dt.onFilterKeyup($event.target.value, col.field, col.filterMatchMode)"
```

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/I2X8yCniM9hvZyyHqn4x?p=preview)

You have to, however, type in the entire word (Apple) for it to work. But I leave that to you to fix :)

Comment: Thanks, but my filter still doesn't work. Do you know what I need to change? 
https://plnkr.co/edit/2MWxw0rfcLsDxmuIYRv9?p=preview

Comment: @kipris Updated my answer